# How do I remove spurious parentheses from a macro argument?

Tags: macros

I want to store the argument of a macro in a temporary variable, but I know in advance that some people will incorrectly enclose the argument in parentheses as well as braces (long story). Specifically, some users will say something like

```
 \bernard{abc}
```

while others will say

```
\bernard{(abc)}
```

I want the macro `\bernard`to store the string `abc` in the temporary variable in both cases. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is Bernard the person? `:-D`

Comment: @Matthew - sadly not. Their name is Legion, for they are many.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\def\bernard#1{\bernard@i#1\@nil}
\def\bernard@i{\@ifnextchar(\bernard@ii\bernard@iii}
\def\bernard@ii(#1)\@nil{\def\bTemp{#1}}
\def\bernard@iii#1\@nil{\def\bTemp{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\bernard{(abc)} \bTemp
\bernard{abc}   \bTemp
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice.  Maybe Ian needs a `\newbernard` macro that defines a command that takes Bernard-style arguments.